# django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory error as part of 6.0.1 to 6.1 upgrade

Tags: kiwi-tcms

Environment: running Kiwi in docker containers from Docker repository on Windows Server 2016. I have not made changes to my clone of the Kiwi repo or the docker images.

Repro:
1. Follow [upgrade steps](http://kiwitcms.org/blog/kiwi-tcms-team/2018/10/20/kiwi-tcms-61/) on blog to upgrade/migrate from Kiwi 6.0 to 6.0.1
2. Repeat steps to upgrade/migrate from Kiwi 6.0.1 to 6.1

Expect:
No errors

Result:
Exception during migration, I clicked around my Kiwi instance after running the migrate command and didn't see anything obviously wrong with the data or associations between cases, plans and runs. But early days...

Full call stack:

```
C:\Kiwi>docker exec -it kiwi_web /Kiwi/manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Kiwi/manage.py", line 12, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 85, in handle
    executor.loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 297, in check_consistent_history
    connection.alias,
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration management.0013_remove_env is applied before its dependency testruns.0019_remove_testruntag_user on database 'default'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argh, this shouldn't happen.

> Repro:
>   1. Follow upgrade steps on blog to upgrade/migrate from Kiwi 6.0 to 6.0.1

Can you describe the steps exactly ? If you did a `git pull` then your docker-compose.yml points to `kiwitcms/kiwi:latest` and you have to manually modify that for the intermediate upgrade step.

> 2. Repeat steps to upgrade/migrate from Kiwi 6.0.1 to 6.1

When did you get the traceback, before step 2 or after step 2 ?

Note: This is similar to  https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/issues/561 and there isn't much we can do about it really.

To debug (I hope you have a backup) you have to revert back to the previous version you had (6.0 as you say), then upgrade to 6.0.1 and post `./manage.py showmigrations`. Then from that try to upgrade to 6.1 and again inspect showmigrations to see if everything is applied.

Note: in the case of traceback during migrate migrations have not been applied so it should be safe to attemp migrate again once you know which is the starting version and target version you are upgrading to.

Comment: I'll just say I'm a software tester and weird stuff happens around me. I followed the steps exactly as written in the blog post. Since it didn't mention the need to edit docker-compose.yml, I was using the version of that file provided by `git pull` (no other options to get a specific label). Is this error safe to ignore? I did do database backups before upgrading and after the two migrations. However, it sounds like a full rollback and reattempted migration will lead to loss of data added since migration.

Comment: Don't ignore the error, upgrade properly otherwise in the future your migrations will become royally screwed.  You have 2 upgrade steps here as I have shown above. For each of them you have to make sure you are using the right docker image, apply the migrations and then repeat. docker-compose.yml in your case points to 6.1 so you are effectively skipping the 6.0.1 upgrade and trying to apply 6.1 migrations directly which fails.  I agree this can be more clear in the docs but that's how docker-compose works.

Comment: I was expecting you to say "don't ignore the error", but was holding out hope. :) I'll retry the migration properly, fortunately, if it all goes badly, our data set is small enough for "rebuild from scratch based on backups" to be a reasonable approach. While I'm probably not your target audience (I'm still figuring out what to do with Docker), additional context and details in the documentation would be really helpful. I also understand where docs fall in the priority list.