# django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory error occurs when installing kiwi tcms

Tags: kiwi-tcms

Use kiwi tcms for some time, running Kiwi TCMS as a Docker container.

This week I upgrade kiwi tcms to latest version 6.2. When I execute command "docker exec -it kiwi_web /Kiwi/manage.py migrate", some error occurs as below. I'm not familiar with django and just use kiwi tcms as a tool. Anyone who can help this? Thanks a lot.

chencjdeMacBook-Air:Kiwi chencj$ docker exec -it kiwi_web /Kiwi/manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Kiwi/manage.py", line 12, in 
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 85, in handle
    executor.loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 297, in check_consistent_history
    connection.alias,
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration linkreference.0001_squashed is applied before its dependency testruns.0004_squashed on database 'default'.

Comment: CJ Chen, which is the starting version you are upgrading from? It is not 6.1.1. As written in our release notes direct  upgrades will only work from 6.1.1 to 6.2. If you are upgrading from an older version you have to go through all the intermediate versions first! This involves pulling these versions from Docker Hub and manually editting your docker-compose.yml file to point to the tagged docker image, not latest.  This is all documented at http://kiwitcms.org/blog/kiwi-tcms-team/2018/11/02/kiwi-tcms-62/

Comment: Hi. Alexander, thx a lot. Yes, as you said, I miss some intermediate version. I will read change log more carefully in future.

Comment: When we upgrading tcms, we just follow steps as:
cd Kiwi/
git pull # to refresh docker-compose.yml
docker-compose down
# make docker-image if you build from source or
docker pull kiwitcms/kiwi  # to fetch latest version from Docker Hub
docker pull centos/mariadb # to fetch the latest version for MariaDB
docker-compose up -d
docker exec -it kiwi_web /Kiwi/manage.py migrate

Comment: I remember we find previous test runs not displayed after upgrade to 5.3.1. Seems version 5.3 brings lots of UI updates. And I find supported upgrade path include 5.3   (or older) -> 5.3.1. But I find this attention from version 5.0 "After upgrade don't forget to: ./manage.py migrate". Shall we execute this command after "docker exec -it kiwi_web /Kiwi/manage.py migrate"? Or they are has same function?

Comment: Thanks a lot for you and your team member to maintenance Kiwi tcms project. I investigate lots of open source project and find this project seems more better. At previous days, I always puzzled how to backup my database. Just now I find backup document on org webpage. So good! I will check more document on org webpage. Also thanks a lot for answering my question patiently.

Comment: ./manage.py migrate  is the same as "docker exec -it kiwi_web /Kiwi/manage.py migrate"

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially the same problem discussed in:

[django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory error as part of 6.0.1 to 6.1 upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52979783/django-db-migrations-exceptions-inconsistentmigrationhistory-error-as-part-of-6)

and is solved by doing intermediate upgrades as shown in:
http://kiwitcms.org/blog/kiwi-tcms-team/2018/11/02/kiwi-tcms-62/